# filling columns based on multiple row values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe `A` with some empty cells that I want to fill to have dataframe `B`. Here is a sample data:

```
A=
    Month   Type    Sale
    2016-01 A       20
    2016-02 A       10
    2016-01 B       40
    2016-02 B       30
    2016-01 C   
    2016-02 C   
    2016-01 D   
    2016-02 D   

B=
    Month   Type    Sale
    2016-01 A       20
    2016-02 A       10
    2016-01 B       40
    2016-02 B       30
    2016-01 C       60
    2016-02 C       40
    2016-01 D       60
    2016-02 D       40
```

Here is what I have done:

```
emptTypes= ['C', 'D']
x = A.groupby('Month', sort = False).Sale.sum()
B['Sale'][B['Type'].isin(emptTypes) & B['Month'].isin(x.index)]=x
```

And nothing happens!

Comment: Nothing happens because you are trying to modify a copy of the original frame. Generally when you do `B['Sale'][boolean]` you're likely to get a copy instead of a view, so when you attempt to modify this nothing happens to the original. To avoid this, try to use `B.loc[boolean, 'Sale']` more often, which in more cases would return a view of the original instead of a copy. See more [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) by [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html):

```
df['Sale'] = df.groupby('Month', sort = False).Sale.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.sum()))
print (df)
     Month Type  Sale
0  2016-01    A  20.0
1  2016-02    A  10.0
2  2016-01    B  40.0
3  2016-02    B  30.0
4  2016-01    C  60.0
5  2016-02    C  40.0
6  2016-01    D  60.0
7  2016-02    D  40.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, since pandas 0.14 you can use `fillna` directly on the dataframe you need to fill in missing values.

```
A.fillna(B)
Out[8]: 
        Type  Sale
Month             
2016-01    A  20.0
2016-02    A  10.0
2016-01    B  40.0
2016-02    B  30.0
2016-01    C  60.0
2016-02    C  40.0
2016-01    D  60.0
2016-02    D  40.0
```

I remember this because a PR was made to incorporate this after I asked a similar question a while back.

This will fill the missing values in `A` with those corresponding to `B` which have matching labels (index/column). This is more general as `A` and `B` do not need to be identically labelled, and the code stays the same when you have a multi-index.

Comment: This looks interesting! But should I first define `B`? I did `B=A.fillna(A)` and it didn't do anything.

Comment: `A.fillna(A)` won't do anything because they are the same frame so no values to use to fill in the missing ones. It's `A.fillna(B)` that you're looking for, so yes you should first define `B`. You can interpret this as "Fill the missing values of `A` with the corresponding values in `B`".